# Xcode 4 method indentation

Tags: xcode, methods, indentation

I know there are a LOT of these topics going on everywhere, but I have a more specific question, as the title suggest.
So, this is how the editor auto-indents:

```
        action = [CCSequence actions:[action1],
                  [action2],
                  [action3],
                  [etc],                 
                  nil];
```

And this is how I'd like it to do it:

```
        action = [CCSequence actions:[action1],
                                     [action2],
                                     [action3],
                                     [etc],

                  nil];
```

Is there any way to make it show like this? I realize methods with multiple arguments get lined up like that because of the ":"-s

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"aa"
                                               message:@"aa"
                                              delegate:nil
                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"aa"
                                     otherButtonTitles:@"aa", 
                      nil];
```

but I really love this layout. Searched everywhere, tried Xcode defaults terminal commands but nothing really did the trick. Actually something did the trick, but it's REALLY unnatural to do it like this.

```
action = [CCSequence actions:[[action1],
                              [action2],
                              [action3],
                              [etc],
                              nil];
```

If I put that extra [ there, they get lined up where I want them, but I have to go back and delete it, obviously, then reindent the nil]; line.

Any help would be REALLY appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

put your code like this:

```
action = [CCSequence actions:[action1],[action2],[action3],[etc],nil];
```

then press enter while the cursor is after the first coma. It will become this:

```
action = [CCSequence actions:[action1],
          [action2],[action3],[etc],nil];
```

if you push [action2] to align with [action1]:

```
action = [CCSequence actions:[action1],
                             [action2],[action3],[etc],nil];
```

the next time you press enter, with the cursor on the second coma, you get this:

```
action = [CCSequence actions:[action1],
                             [action2],
                             [action3],[etc],nil];
```

further enters on the comas will keep things aligned.

Is this enough for you?

Comment: I think that he knows how to make a carriage return and that he is actualizy looking for an automatic way...

Comment: What user931303 is saying is that if you manually line up 2 members of a comma separated list, the rest will align automatically upon carriage return.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your reply. Secondly, I should have mentioned I use auto-indentation for "Return" and your suggestion only works with it off. I could live with this, so at least I have *some* solution, but as Macmade said, indeed I'm looking for an automatic way for this, I'd like the code to look nice as I'm typing it.